# How to toggle element attribute by checkbox selection jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I need to toggle attribute 'disable' in button by checkbox selection? Please help

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#checkbox").click(function() {
    $(".btn-submit").attr("checked");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox">
<button class="btn-submit" disabled>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed your code to accomplish what you need

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#checkbox").change(function() {
    $(".btn-submit").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox">
<button class="btn-submit" disabled=true>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something like the below:

```
$("#checkbox").click(function() {
    if ($('#checkbox').prop("checked") == true) {
        $('.btn-submit').prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $('.btn-submit').prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Line 2 will check to see if the box is checked. If it is, it will set the disabled property of the submit button to `false`. If it is unchecked, it will reverse the action and disable the button again.

When enabling buttons which follow a set of steps, always ask yourself, is there any way an end user can get around this (in this instance, trying to uncheck the box)

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this.checked` to determine if the checkbox being changed is ticked or not.

You can then use `.prop("disabled", disabled_true_false)` to disable the button.

Updated snippet to only enable the button once the tickbox has been ticked:

```js
$("#checkbox").change(function() {
  $(".btn-submit").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox">
<button class="btn-submit" disabled>Submit</button>
```